# How to get firebase documents with fields comparing with each other?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to programming and I have firebase documents which have two fields "totalreceivables" and "totalreceived" and all I want is to get documents which "totalreceived" is greater than  "totalreceivables" here without any success so far.

I tried everything i could find in the documentation for a 3 days i'm desperate.

I am using Javascript

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
db.collection("historyCards").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  setupHistoryCardListForBackOffice(snapshot.docs);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRoxw.jpg)

Comment: I'd take a look at their query docs. Looks pretty straightforward: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Answer (score 1):

While this is easy with SQL, it isn't possible with a single Cloud Firestore query, as this type of query doesn't scale massively.  You can only compare fields with constant values that you provide through the API.  If you absolutely need to get the results, you will have to query for all the documents in the collection, then write code on the client to compare each of the documents to each other to find a match.

If you need to perform this sort of query a lot, Cloud Firestore might not be the best database for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the application I am trying to build doesn't need that much of use. I need to get the results. would you give me the example how can I write code to compare to each other on client side.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's expected that the person asking the question make an attempt at solving the problem, then post what isn't working as expected.  This is not a forum to ask for sample code or get people to write code for you.

Comment: I am truly sorry for that but as I mentioned I am new to programming and I was just asking for example so I can get the concept.